# How to use log or debug within stored procedure of PgSql?

Tags: postgresql, logging

I want to debug or use log for a PgSql stored Procedure. Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 2):

The usual method is to use RAISE NOTICE inside of a PLPGSQL function:

```
create function test(some_string text) returns void as $$
  BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Some string: %', some_string;
  END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

# select test('!');
psql: NOTICE:  Some string: !
 test
------

(1 row)
```

Whether this message actually shows up in the logs and for the client depends on the settings of log_min_messages and client_min_messages, respectively.